# javascript and webworker

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

Why can't a javascript file in a WebWorker access document object, when a normal external javascript file can access the document object?
Or can a WebWorker access a document object? Because in w3schools it is given that
since webworkers are external javascript files, they cannot access the document object, window object, parent object.

Comment: Usually, w3schools is **not** a reliable source. You'd better use the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers) instead.

Comment: WebWorker have access to the BOM. But for keeping them non-concurrent with the main script, which has access to the DOM, you canno't access the DOM. But why should someone even want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't access the DOM because then browsers would have to add lots of complexity to ensure their DOM code was thread safe.